# Are Windows 7 product keys language-dependent?

Tags: windows-7, language, license-key

I am a student in a computer science school which is part of the MSDN Academic Alliance program.

Recently Windows 7 Pro showed up in the list of available software on ELMS. Problem is, it is in the French language (I am in a French school).

I would prefer to have Windows 7 in English. Question is: can I use the product key I got for the French version when installing an English (and otherwise identical) version of Windows 7?

In other words, is the product key dependant of the product language?

Comment: Careful, you ask in the text the opposite question from the title.

Comment: I miss my SO rep... could someone swap "language-dependent" with "language-independent"?

Comment: And inverse the answer :p

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No. Product keys are SKU dependent. They are not language dependent.

Answer (score 0):

Windows itself became largely language agnostic starting with Vista.  Once Windows is installed with the French disk you can change the language and everything should convert.

That said, versions for different countries may have different software based on different legal requirements (i.e. Windows 7 N versions for Europe that don't have Windows Media Player).